# Solving an SDE: $dX=-Xdt+e^{-t}dW$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-differential-equations

I have the following problem which comes with the solution, but I am unable to obtain the solution... Any help would be greatly appreciated - I am preparing for finals :( Thanks a lot!

The SDE that I need to solve is $dX=-Xdt+e^{-t}dW$. The solution is $X(t)=(X_0+W(t))e^{-t}$

I have noticed that 
$$dW=e^{t}dX+e^{t}Xdt=d(e^tX)$$

So I have tried with $Z=e^tX$ and get $dZ=2e^t(dX+X)$, but I am stuck there now :/ (and I am not sure if that $dZ$ is correct either because we are not shown how the professor got the final result).

Answer (score 2):

I think you were not quite right in calculating $dZ$. You had the right path though.

$$dZ=e^t X dt+e^t dX+e^t dt dX$$
$$dZ=e^t Xdt+e^t(-Xdt+e^{-t}dW)+0$$
$$dZ=(e^tX-e^tX)dt+dW$$
$$dZ=dW$$
$$Z=X_0+W(t)$$
$$X(t)=(X_0+W(t))e^{-t}$$

Comment: should not dZ be $dZ= e^t dtX + e^t dX$? Where did you get that cross term from? and you dont even need it for the rest of your method. And if I am wrong and you do have it why is it zero?

Comment: The cross term is Ito's Product rule! In this case, it ends up being 0. Ito's product rule states: for two Ito processes, $X,Y$, $d(XY)=YdX+XdY+dXdY$. Here, $Y$ is an Ito process with 0 diffusion so it ends up not mattering. http://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/mcudina/Sections20_1_2_3

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have another question regarding Ito´s product rule... How do you do it in this case? $Z=e^{-\sigma W(t)+\frac{\sigma t}{2}}X$, so we would need $dZ$.

Comment: You would have to break it into chunks. Meaning, what is $d(e^{-\sigma W(t)+\frac{\sigma t}{2}})$? This can be calculated by Ito's formula. If you have that, then you can apply Ito's product rule.